# Respected Haskamot

Tags: books-generally, rabbis

Sometimes I find a interesting looking Sefer (I know...I know...don't judge a book by it's cover) and want to take a look at the content. To my surprise, there are many Haskamot (approbations) from Rabbanim that I've never heard of. Who is the most "accepted" Haskma for a Sefer nowadays? (please no opinions, but logic)

Comment: Do you want the books-generally tag or the jewish-books tag? What kind of "Sefer" are you talking about?

Comment: As long as they have actually read the book.

Comment: they dont always read sometimes go on knowledge of the person

Comment: Yes, @simchashatorah. Although that is true, I was pointing out what I think is most important in a haskama.

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: I don't see how "Who is the most 'accepted' ..." can possibly be answered with logic.

Answer (score 1):

ISrael:Reb Ovadiah Yosef, Reb Eliyashiv, and Rav Kanevsky,Rav Shternbach ,Rav Abba Shaul

America: Rav Belsky, Rav Feinstein (either one), Reb Shmuel Kamenetsky

Simply put these Rabonim have name recognition and not anyone will get a Haskamah from them but sometimes you have to read between the lines if the Haskamah addresses the contents or the Author saying I know him to be a good man that is a warning sign sometimes they will Humor the author for other reasons.

Comment: you are right i fixed it

Comment: For the record, If I see haskamot from those people,  and the book was written after the 1980s, I do not trust that the book was ever read by them.